# Starting share activity from ADB shell

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, adb

I'm starting a sharing activity from ADB shell.

Specifically I am trying to achieve the same as this (working) java-snippet:

```
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File yourFile = new File(dir, "/_tmp/1.jpg");

    Uri yourFileUri = Uri.fromFile(yourFile);

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, yourFileUri);
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.snapchat.android");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Here is the commands I am using:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t image/jpeg --es android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/_tmp/1.jpg com.snapchat.android --grant-read-uri-permission
```

The issue I am currently facing is that the snapchat app will open and load, flash black for a second but fails to load the image.

I have checked that the path to the image is working by issuing the following commands, and opening the image in the android gallery:

```
adb shell am start -t image/jpeg -d file:///storage/emulated/0/_tmp/1.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Using the command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t image/jpeg --es android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/_tmp/1.jpg com.snapchat.android/com.snapchat.android.LandingPageActivity --grant-read-uri-permission
```

Gives the same result, however I compared it to the actual call in DDMS, see the difference here:

Log by sharing manually through the phone:

```
10-19 18:01:54.020: D/HtcShareActivity(21561): onItemClick: position=0 activity=com.snapchat.android/com.snapchat.android.LandingPageActivity

10-19 18:01:54.061: I/ActivityManager(724): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/jpeg flg=0x1 cmp=com.snapchat.android/.LandingPageActivity (has clip) (has extras)} from uid 10078 on display 0
```

Log by using the ADB command:

```
10-19 18:04:29.096: I/ActivityManager(724): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/jpeg flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.snapchat.android/.LandingPageActivity (has extras)} from uid 2000 on display 0
```

As you can see the `(has clip)` is not present in the ADB call.

Could it be that `--grant-read-uri-permission` isn't "working" or at least not giving sufficient permission?

How do I test and ultimately solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out I wasn't sending any real image data, I was simply sending a string by using `--es`, however the a URI was needed, and therefore I should have used `--eu`.

Updating the following command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t image/jpeg --es android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/_tmp/1.jpg com.snapchat.android/com.snapchat.android.LandingPageActivity --grant-read-uri-permission
```

To:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t image/jpeg --eu android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/_tmp/1.jpg com.snapchat.android/com.snapchat.android.LandingPageActivity --grant-read-uri-permission
```

Solved my issue.

It was not due to leaving out declaration of the main activity that @Dus suggested. (Good thought though.)

The command can be simplified all the way down to:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t image/jpeg --eu android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/_tmp/1.jpg com.snapchat.android
```

Comment: good for you - you found the command which does what you wanted. but your root cause analysis is wrong. what fixed it for you was not `--es` vs `--eu` but `image/*` vs `image/jpeg`. shell globbing (wildcard expansion) was ruining your original command.

Comment: @AlexP. I can assure you I wasted more time on solving the `--es` vs `--eu` riddle than forgetting to edit out the copy and paste I did in the OP. Good eye though, let me edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You're opening your application with the intent, but, you're not declaring which Activity should handle the intent, which is why you see a flicker and then close - an Activity needs to handle the intent.

You need to declare in your command whats the `MainActivity` that is supposed to be handling the intent.

For example :

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t image/* --es 
android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/_tmp/1.jpg 
com.snapchat.android/FULL_PATH_OF_YOUR_ACTIVITY
```

where `FULL_PATH_OF_YOUR_ACTIVITY` should be the activity declared as main activity in your manifest.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t image/* --es 
android.intent.extra.STREAM file:///storage/emulated/0/_tmp/1.jpg 
com.snapchat.android/com.snapchat.android.sub.MainActivity
```

Sample manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.snapchat.android">

    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.snapchat.android.sub.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response. I went through it and edited the OP with my findings.

Comment: I finally have been able to solve my issue. While your response did not address the main issue directly, it did push me into the right direction. Therefore I will reward you with the bounty (in 8 hours). Thanks for helping.